New battery remains in pending-charge status, need to reboot to start charging again
I had to replace the battery on a Lenovo P53 (swelling battery).
The only replacement I could find (Lenovo no longer has the model in stock it seems) was a
Weetyut brand battery from Amazon.
The battery works and even seems to have the nominal capacity.

The first time I unplugged the AC and plugged it back after a while, the battery started charging again.
In a second attempt, I let the battery discharge to 10%, then plugged the charger back and the battery didn't charge (waited a few hours...).
I rebooted and the battery charged again
I let the battery discharge to  50%, plugged the charger back, and again it is not charging (also waited a few hours).

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 reports:
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMD
  model:                02DL028
  serial:               178
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 22 Jul 2024 09:49:01 (93 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              45.73 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         89.19 Wh
    energy-full-design:  87 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0118371 W
    voltage:             11.388 V
    charge-cycles:       4
    percentage:          51%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-good-charging-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1721634541  0.012   pending-charge

and the contents of /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/:
                                   alarm: 4459000
                                capacity: 51
                          capacity_level: Normal
            charge_control_end_threshold: 100
          charge_control_start_threshold: 0
                  charge_start_threshold: 0
                   charge_stop_threshold: 100
                             cycle_count: 4
                             energy_full: 89190000
                      energy_full_design: 87000000
                              energy_now: 45610000
                        hwmon2/in0_input: 11385
                             hwmon2/name: BAT0
                      hwmon2/power/async: disabled
       hwmon2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: 
                    hwmon2/power/control: auto
        hwmon2/power/runtime_active_kids: 0
        hwmon2/power/runtime_active_time: 0
            hwmon2/power/runtime_enabled: disabled
             hwmon2/power/runtime_status: unsupported
     hwmon2/power/runtime_suspended_time: 0
              hwmon2/power/runtime_usage: 0
                           hwmon2/uevent: 
                            manufacturer: SMD
                              model_name: 02DL028
                             power/async: disabled
              power/autosuspend_delay_ms: 
                           power/control: auto
                               power_now: 0
               power/runtime_active_kids: 0
               power/runtime_active_time: 0
                   power/runtime_enabled: disabled
                    power/runtime_status: unsupported
            power/runtime_suspended_time: 0
                     power/runtime_usage: 0
                                 present: 1
                           serial_number:   178
                                  status: Not charging
                              technology: Li-poly
                                    type: Battery
                      voltage_min_design: 11250000
                             voltage_now: 11385000

Any way to avoid rebooting to charge the battery? Is the battery defective (or not emulating the official one correctly)?
Running Ubuntu 22.04
Edit: installed the TLP package, tried sudo tlp chargeonce BAT0, and even though TLP answers Charging starts now, nothing happens.

After contacting the vendor, it appears that this is is "normal" on a new battery, the full capabilities are unlocked only after a few charge cycles, which means:

let the battery discharge,
power-off
make sure the charger is plugged in and start the PC

After 4-5 such cycles, the battery starts behaving normally and appears fully compatible.
